# Calculate turtle variable for different patch types

Tags: sorting, foreach, conditional-statements, netlogo

I'm trying to calculate a turtle variable (`district-winner`) for every value of a certain patch variable (`district`). Patch `district` ranges from 0 to 100. The patches are also endowed with a feature `votes`. The turtle (`party`) receives a patches' `votes` if it is the closest turtle to that patch. For every patch *district* I wish to indicate the turtle that receives most votes in that particular patch `district`, and stall the information in some variable (e.g. `district-vote` or `district-winner`). That is where I got stuck.

I have tried working with `foreach` and `sort-by`, but so far I haven't managed to create a code without error that accounts for every different `district` value. The code for assigning votes to some closest turtle works (see code). But I haven't figured out how to calculate the *votes* won by turtles per `district` for each district.

How to create a turtle variable that is conditionalised on some patch variable value?

Working code, relevant lines:

```
to update-support
  ask patches [set closest-party min-one-of parties [distance myself]]
      ;;patches find their closest party
  ask parties [set mysize sum [votes] of patches with [closest-party = myself]] 
      ;;each party sums the votes on patches for which it is the closest party    
end
```

Some attempt to run the code for different patch *districts*:

```
to update support
 ask patches [
   set closest-party min-one-of parties [distance myself]
     ;;patches find their closest party
   set closest-party-list [ (list closest-party) ] of patches
      (foreach district-number
        [set district-vote-map map [ifelse-value (? != district) [? = district] [?]] closest- 
        party-list])
   ;;and then link this closest-party-list to some code for asking parties?? 
   ]
  ]
end
```

Another attempt

```
to update support
  ask patches [
    set closest-party min-one-of parties [distance myself]]
        ;;patches find their closest party
  ask parties [
    set district-vote [
      (foreach [(district) of patches] sum [votes] of patches with [closest-party = myself] and 
      [district = [?]])]
end
```

Comment: What version of Netlogo are you using? After 5.0 they changed the syntax for anonymous procedures, so you no longer use those question marks. [Programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures)

Comment: Hi Leirs! I am using Netlogo 5.3.1. I had issues converting my code to Netlogo 6

Comment: It's not clear to me whether each patch has one value of district, or several.  I.e., does district vary over patches, or time, or both?  Can you give an example of the party variable you are trying to create?  E.g., the number of votes a party receives from all patches with a particular value of district?

Comment: I suspect you'd get more help if you DID convert your model to Netlogo 6.2 or 6.2.2. You could ask here about whatever conversion problems you have.   Putting this into one statement could use the current anonymous block syntax.      Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

I answered in google groups.   The routine "Tally" does relevant calculations and can easily be tweaked to cope with ties if you want to.  I didn't even try to compress this into one long command line.  I added party names.  Here's the tally section, the rest is in netlogo-users group.   I didn't try to make it polished but it seems to work.

By doing things the long way I never needed to use an anonymous block so I think it should run in any version of NetLogo back to and including 5.

```
;;==========================  Wade added 6/17/2022

to tally
  ;; to make party-names equal to party-number so my code fits your code
  set party-names []
  ask parties [ set name self set party-names lput name party-names]
  set party-names sort party-names



  print (word "Number of PATCHes: "  ( count patches  ) )
  print (word "Number of VOTES: " (   sum [votes] of patches ) )
  print " "
  ask parties [ print (word name " got this many PATCHES: " (count patches with [closest-party = [name] of myself ])) ]

  print " "
    ask parties
  [
    print
    (word
        name " got this many VOTES: "
      (sum [votes] of patches with [closest-party = [name] of myself ])
    )
  ]


  ;; generate a list of districts in use
  let district-list  ( remove-duplicates ( sort [district] of patches ) )
  print (word "list of districts in use: "  district-list )

  ;;===================================================================================
  let working-dislist district-list
  let dist 0
  let dist-count 0
  let total-vote 0

  while [ length working-dislist > 0 ][
    set dist first working-dislist
    set dist-count sum [votes] of patches with [ district = dist ]
    print (word " for district: " dist " this many votes: " dist-count)
    set total-vote total-vote + dist-count
    set working-dislist butfirst working-dislist
  ]
    print ( word "========================\nTotal votes by district: " total-vote )

  print " now analyzing by district and party "
  set working-dislist district-list
  let working-party-list party-names
  let pname " unkown "

  set dist 0
  set dist-count 0
  set total-vote 0
  let dp-sum 0

  while [ is-list? working-dislist and length working-dislist > 0 ][
    set dist first working-dislist
    set dist-count sum [votes] of patches with [ district = dist ]
    print (word " ------> for district: " dist " this many votes: " dist-count " broken out below" )

    set working-party-list party-names
    set   dp-sum 0
    let district-winner ""
    let winning-votes -99

    while [ is-list? working-party-list  and length working-party-list > 0 ][
      set pname first working-party-list
      set working-party-list butfirst working-party-list
      let details sum [votes] of patches with [ district = dist and closest-party = pname ]
      set dp-sum (dp-sum + details)
      print ( word ".....in district " dist " party " pname ": has this many votes: " details )
      if ( details > winning-votes ) [
        set winning-votes   details
        set district-winner   pname
      ]

    ]
    print (word ".................... subtotal: " dp-sum "  District Winner with " winning-votes " is " district-winner "\n")
      set dp-sum 0
    set working-party-list party-names

    set total-vote total-vote + dist-count
    set working-dislist butfirst working-dislist
  ]
    print ( word "======== \nTotal votes by party by district: " total-vote )
   ;;===================================================================================




end
```

The output produces totals at increasing levels of granularity ending with what I THINK you want.  You still need to break ties but that's easy to do with this code.

> ------> for district: 49 this many votes: 12801.954344857973 broken
> out below .....in district 49 party (party 0): has this many votes:
> 302.9649675865895 .....in district 49 party (party 1): has this many votes: 1457.5052709454735 .....in district 49 party (party 2): has
> this many votes: 0 .....in district 49 party (party 3): has this many
> votes: 830.4743848217157 .....in district 49 party (party 4): has this
> many votes: 1393.6496323186223 .....in district 49 party (party 5):
> has this many votes: 4418.5271517613455 .....in district 49 party
> (party 6): has this many votes: 147.01914867815847 .....in district 49
> party (party 7): has this many votes: 3005.0957136873785 .....in
> district 49 party (party 8): has this many votes: 976.2462740954787
> .....in district 49 party (party 9): has this many votes:
> 270.4718009632105 .................... subtotal: 12801.954344857973  District Winner with 4418.5271517613455 is (party 5)